# ffmpeg: how to add pixellate effect?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to blur some uploaded videos and encoded them.
Infact by blur, it means pixellate them so "big squares" appear and blur it.

Any idea on how I can do that ? (ffmpeg would be great, by any command line windows tool should be ok)

Thanks.

Comment: Yarek, did you figure out how to do it with a section rather than the full video?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### FFmpeg can support the frei0r filters which includes pixeliz0r

[image: original]
[image: pixeliz0r]

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "frei0r=filter_name=pixeliz0r:filter_params=0.02|0.02" output
```

The two pixeliz0r `filter_params` parameters are:

- BlockSizeX: horizontal size of one "pixel"
- BlockSizeY: vertical size of one "pixel"

Larger values will create larger blocks.

#### Where to get ffmpeg with frei0r support

- Windows users can get the "full build" from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/).
- Linux users can download or compile:

  - Download ffmpeg with frei0r support at [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).
  - Or compile ffmpeg by installing whatever package provides `frei0r.h` (such as *frei0r-plugins-dev* in Ubuntu or *frei0r-devel* in CentOS) and then add `--enable-frei0r` to your ffmpeg configure. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile Guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).
- macOS users can use [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg). You may need the `--with-frei0r` option.

#### More info

- [frei0r homepage](https://www.dyne.org/software/frei0r/)
- [FFmpeg frei0r filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#frei0r-1)

Comment: How do you do this just for an area of the shot (such as when you want to cover someone face?)

Comment: @Doug any chance you found the answer to your question?

Comment: I have ffmpeg but how can I enable frei0r with it. Consider me a novice to ffmpeg,

Comment: @FaisalMq What is your OS?

Comment: Ok got it. I downloaded ffmpeg that's already enabled for pixeliz0r from the link given on [mplayer](http://oss.netfarm.it/mplayer/)  site: [ffmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/files/FFmpeg/git-N-74566-g531b0a3/FFmpeg-x86_64-N-74566-g531b0a3.7z/download)

Comment: This seems to corrupt the video for me. VLC can play it, but other programs, such as Windows Media player, or uploading to Twitter can't process it. Reencoding didn't fix it either

Comment: @pigeonburger Need to see your ffmpeg command and the complete log. You can use a pastebin site and provide a link in a comment.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to install the frei0r plugin for this, there's an alternative way.

```
dimensions=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of "csv=p=0:s=\:" input)

ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v] scale='iw/15:-1', scale='$dimensions:flags=neighbor'" output
```

This scales down the input size (in this example, by 15) and then scales it back up to the original dimensions. The `flags=neighbor` tells ffmpeg to use the nearest neighbor rescaling algorithm which results in the pixelated effect. You can change the block size by changing the number 15.

The first line is needed to find out the input's original dimensions and scale back directly to it, otherwise the scaling down and scaling up might result in rounding errors that slightly alter the size of the output.

Comment: You can eliminate `head` and `sed` by using `"csv=p=0:s=\:"`.

Comment: @llogan thanks, good point. Edited, but I'll leave the `head` in for when the input has a video and audio stream, because you get a blank line for the dimensions of the audio stream.

Comment: The blank line can be avoided with the addition of `-select_streams v:0`.

Comment: One more pro of this solution is that it works with High output profile, whereas frei0r can only output High Progressive. This is important if you want to merge videos without re-encoding, as profile must be identical.

Answer (score 1):

The [pixelize filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pixelize) can do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf pixelize=300 output
```

Replace 300 with your intensity (limited to 1024).