# ffmpeg windows: how to run ffmpeg -i input -filter:v frei0r=pixeliz0r=0.02:0.02 output

Tags: plugins, ffmpeg

I run **ffmpeg** on **Windows**.

I try to run

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter:v frei0r=pixeliz0r=0.02:0.02 ouput.avi
```

I have this error:

```
No such filter: 'frei0r
Error opening filters!
```

When I run `ffmpeg.exe` I got:

```
ffmpeg version git-N-30610-g1929807, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  7 2011 15:55:06 with gcc 4.5.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-memalign-hack --enable-
runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libo
pencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --
enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger
 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --disable-outdev=sdl -
-pkg-config=pkg-config
```

Note the `--enable-frei0r` above.

Any idea where I can get the ffmpeg for **windows with frei0r enabled and working** ?

Comment: --enable-frei0r in configure does not imply ---enable-filter=frei0r did you download it from somewhere or built it yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok finally got it going: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=312&p=2716#p2716

Basically download some frei0r plugin dll's (http://oss.netfarm.it/mplayer-win32.php has some, http://people.videolan.org/~jb/vlmc/effects.7z has some)

then `set FREI0R_PATH=c:\vids\effects\`

Then it should "just work" like

`ffmpeg.exe -loglevel debug -i input_file -vf "frei0r=glow:20" -t 10 output_file`

GL!

Comment: could you help me with that?

Comment: setpts isn't a freior filter...maybe ask it as a new question?

Comment: I did, but noone answers :( I asked on `zeranoe.com` too, but noone knows the answer neither. Maybe I'll just use `mencoder`, at least it work fine...

Comment: [:a link:](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1378&p=0&e=0) please note, that You have to be registered to even read forum...

Answer (score 0):

From [ffmpeg: how to add pixellate effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093549/ffmpeg-how-to-add-pixellate-effect) , you have a link to http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ . It seems these are Windows build with frei0r enabled.

Comment: yes: I downloaded it from there. But it gives me that error !

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you much :-)

Answer (score 0):

When using `-loglevel debug` option, ffmpeg gives information where it looks for frei0r plugins.

On windows you need to create folders following this information. For instance create path: `C:\usr\lib\frei0r-1\` and put all filter DLLs there.