# FFMPEG - add pixelated circular filter over video

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, pixelate

please is possible to create circular pixelated filter to cover face. Something like this: [ffmpeg: how to add pixellate effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093549/ffmpeg-how-to-add-pixellate-effect) but only in circle

Comment: What commands have you tried with ffmpeg? Documentation for filter is here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Comment: I am not familiar with ffmpeg, its for my co-worker who said that its not possible and mad only square filter

Comment: That sounds off topic to me if you are not familiar with ffmpeg. Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Is the scene static, or will the face be moving around? If it is static is may be possible with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: its video and i want to have circular mask (like this but circular: http://postimg.org/image/x5f1ucy3d/ ). face is moving, but I want to have it only on one fixed position. But be able to place more then one. I will put here ffmpeg command how is it made square later

Comment: Mask command:  -vf \"".$filter."\"   where filter is: $filter="split [main][tmp];[tmp] crop=$velikost:$velikost:$A:$B, scale=$velikost:$velikost, boxblur=5:5 [scale];[main][scale] overlay=$x-$polomer:$y-$polomer [out]";

Comment: please I didnt find soultion until now, can somebody show me the way?

Comment: any chance you found an answer?